# Full horizontal justification in table

Tags: tables, justification

I want the table to output **exactly** as shown in the picture (the location of words is important). The first three lines should be fully justified (left and right), and the last line should justify to the left. I am looking for an answer that is reproducible over different examples rather than being strictly only applicable to this example. To reiterate, it is the location of words that is important, not the look (typeface etc).

Example:
[image: what it should look like]

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{p{8.5cm} l}
You grow emotionally involved. You get to know & relationship \\
this child so intimately that you grow close to the child & involved \\
and you know you despair, you're frustrated. You feel \\
angry - I feel anger a lot of the time. & emotions
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

This is what I get:
[image: mwe output]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{@{}>{\parfillskip=0pt}p{8.5cm} l}
You grow emotionally involved. You get to know & relationship \\
this child so intimately that you grow close to the child & involved \\
and you know you despair, you're frustrated. You feel \\
angry -- I feel anger a lot of the time.\hfill\mbox{}& emotions
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks David. I am adapting this answer for my own purposes (multiple separate paragraphs). I presume I am just adapting the 8.5cm each time?

Comment: Seemingly so. Seems a bit clunky having to do it by hand, but so be it. TYVM. :)

Comment: @Frank_Zafka I am not sure what you mean by "having to do by hand" that was part of the requirement in your question wasn't it? Normally you would use automatic line breaking and marginal notes you could still do that with forced line breaks (matching an existing publication, I assume?) but tabular is perhaps simpler in the forced line break case.

Comment: Hi David. You answer does what I ask. I'll leave it there. Many thanks.

Answer (score 5):

(I modified this answer after the OP clarified that reproducing the exact placement of the words across lines was crucial.)

I suggest you employ a `tabularx` environment with two columns; the left-hand column should be `p{8.5cm}`, the second should be of type `X`(to take up the residual available width). Next, don't use line breaks in the left-hand columns, and use `\newline` to create the required line breaks in the right-hand column. Finally, if any fine-tuning is necessary, use "ties", i.e., unbreakable spaces, to suppress unwanted line breaks. For the example at hand, the only required tie is between `this` and `child`; hence, replace `this child` with `this~child`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}  % for "tabularx" environment
\usepackage{newpxtext} % optional, for Palatino clone text font
\begin{document}

\noindent
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{}
    >{\sloppy\frenchspacing}p{8.5cm} 
    @{\qquad} X@{}}
You grow emotionally involved. You get to know
this~child so intimately that you grow close to the child
and you know you despair, you're frustrated. You feel
angry -- I feel anger a lot of the time.
&
relationship \newline involved \newline\newline emotions \\
\end{tabularx}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4):

Sure that you want a table for this?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[rmargin=4in]{geometry}
\begin{document}

You grow emotionally involved\marginpar{relationship involved}. You get to know this child so intimately that you grow close to the child and you know you despair, you're frustrated. You feel angry - I feel anger\marginpar{emotions} a lot of the time.

\end{document}
```